# How can I compile a source member from local workspace in an IBMi environment using VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, rpg

We are trying to utilize GitHub with VS code for IBMi related development.
Intent is to checkout a Github branch using VS code into a local workspace , make required code changes , compile in an IBMi envt , unit test in IBMi envt and then push the code back to Github.

We tried creating CRTBNDRPG compile action with file type as 'Local File(workspace)' but realized that this may not work as the source is not physically present in IBMi.

Is there any option where we can directly compile an RPG code from local workspace rather than having to manually copy the source from local workspace to IBMi and then execute compile action ?

Comment: You could store the code in the IFS, and set up a share that VSCode could use as a source library. In addition, seems that in the past I have set up a Windows share that IBM i could read and write to, but I don't remember how I did it.

Comment: Thanks @jmarkmurphy ......do you have any suggestions on how to move the code directly to a IFS directory either from GitHub or from local workspace ?